# Backup Failed - Time Machine couldn't back up to "disk name"

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, macbook-pro, external-disk

I have a 2013 MacBook Air running Mavericks. I bought a Nifty drive and a top of the line micro sd. When I shutdown my computer, turn it back on and go to backup no problem, but if the lid is shut and then opened I get the following error: "Backup Failed - Time Machine couldn't back up to 'disk name'" I then have to restart if I want to backup. Any suggestions?

Comment: This normally doesn't do any harm I guess, since TM makes local backups every hour and saves these to the sd afterwards. But in general I'd say: don't use a SD card for backups - they are meant to be used in Cameras etc.

Comment: If you reboot and type the two commands into terminal - first `df` and then `tmutil latestbackup`, it might help us define the drives you have attached and dig into the real cause. Press return after each command and ping me after the edit (comment @bmike) if you want help editing the formatting or making sense of the output